# Using magit-add-section-hook in spacemacs startup

Tags: magit

I am attempting to use `magit-add-section-hook` in `dotspacemacs/user-init`.

```
(defun dotspacemacs/user-config ()
  ;; Magit pull submodules.  Don't know why this fails.
  (magit-add-section-hook 'magit-status-sections-hook 'magit-insert-modules-overview 'append t)
  )
```

This results in the following error while loading:

***(Spacemacs) Error in dotspacemacs/user-config: Symbol’s function definition is void: magit-add-section-hook***
AND the `magit-add-section-hook` is not defined in emacs.  Other magit operations appear to function properly.

When I remove the `(magit-add-section-hook ...)` from the `dotspacemacs/user-init`and restart the function `magit-add-section-hook` loads normally and can be used with the above expression.

*** Version Info***:

- Emacs: GNU Emacs 27.1 (build 1, x86)64-mingw32) of 2020-11-19
- Spacemacs: 0.300.0@27.1
- Magit: 20211011.1135 [>=3.3.0], Git 2.30.1, Emacs 27.1, windows-nt

Answer (score 2):

You can't call a function that hasn't been defined, and that function won't be defined until the `magit-section.el` library has been loaded.

For Magit you're better to deal with the main `magit.el` library though.  It will (indirectly) load magit-section.el along with the other core libraries, and in your particular case you're dealing with things which are defined in more than one of those libraries.

You can `(require 'magit)` to load it forcibly, but I would do this:

```el
(with-eval-after-load "magit"
  (magit-add-section-hook ...))
```

Comment: With the proposed I get "Cannot add function to undefined hook variable magit-status-sections-hook"

```(with-eval-after-load 'magit-section (magit-add-section-hook 'magit-status-sections-hook 'magit-insert-modules-overview '(append t)))```

When I use the brute-force:
```(add-hook 'magit-mode-hook (lambda () (magit-add-section-hook 'magit-status-sections-hook 'magit-insert-modules-overview '(append t))))```
It works (except for the append) portion.

Comment: `magit-status-sections-hook` is defined in a different library which is loaded later.  I've edited the answer to deal with `magit.el` instead, which eliminates any such sequencing issues.